# Unity C# Errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having some problems with understanding the error messages, have gone through my code to find what is wrong, but can't find any. Please help! I get 25 similar error messages, and they all look like this:

Assets/Scenes/Scripts/GameController.cs(120,113): error CS1061: 'GridSpace' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no accessible extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'GridSpace' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public Image panel;
    public Text text;
    public Button button;
    public Sprite playerImage;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerColor
{
    public Color panelColor;
    public Color textColor;
}

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GridSpace[] gridSpaceList;
    public GameObject gameOverPanel;
    public Text gameOverText;
    public GameObject restartButton;
    public Player playerX;
    public Player playerO;
    public PlayerColor activePlayerColor;
    public PlayerColor inactivePlayerColor;
    public GameObject startInfo;

    private string playerSide;
    private int moveCount;

    public Sprite GetPlayerSideImage()
    {
        if (playerSide == "X")
        {
            return playerX.playerImage;
        }
        else
        {
            return playerO.playerImage;
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        SetGameControllerReferenceOnButtons();
        gameOverPanel.SetActive(false);
        moveCount = 0;
        restartButton.SetActive(false);
    }

    void SetGameControllerReferenceOnButtons()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridSpaceList.Length; i++)
        {
            gridSpaceList[i].SetGameControllerReference(this);
        }
    }

    public void SetStartingSide(string startingSide)
    {
        playerSide = startingSide;
        if (playerSide == "X")
        {
            SetPlayerColors(playerX, playerO);
        }
        else
        {
            SetPlayerColors(playerO, playerX);
        }

        StartGame();
    }

    void StartGame()
    {
        SetBoardInteractable(true);
        SetPlayerButtons(false);
        startInfo.SetActive(false);
    }

    public string GetPlayerSide()
    {
        return playerSide;
    }

    public void EndTurn()
    {
        moveCount++;

        if (gridSpaceList[0].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[1].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[2].text == playerSide)
        {
            GameOver(playerSide);
        }
        else if (gridSpaceList[3].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[4].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[5].text == playerSide)
        {
            GameOver(playerSide);
        }
        else if (gridSpaceList[6].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[7].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[8].text == playerSide)
        {
            GameOver(playerSide);
        }
        else if (gridSpaceList[0].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[3].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[6].text == playerSide)
        {
            GameOver(playerSide);
        }
        else if (gridSpaceList[1].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[4].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[7].text == playerSide)
        {
            GameOver(playerSide);
        }
        else if (gridSpaceList[2].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[5].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[8].text == playerSide)
        {
            GameOver(playerSide);
        }
        else if (gridSpaceList[0].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[4].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[8].text == playerSide)
        {
            GameOver(playerSide);
        }
        else if (gridSpaceList[2].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[4].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[6].text == playerSide)
        {
            GameOver(playerSide);
        }
        else if (moveCount >= 9)
        {
            GameOver("draw");
        }
        else
        {
            ChangeSides();
        }
    }

    void ChangeSides()
    {
        playerSide = (playerSide == "X") ? "O" : "X";
        if (playerSide == "X")
        {
            SetPlayerColors(playerX, playerO);
        }
        else
        {
            SetPlayerColors(playerO, playerX);
        }
    }

    void SetPlayerColors(Player newPlayer, Player oldPlayer)
    {
        newPlayer.panel.color = activePlayerColor.panelColor;
        newPlayer.text.color = activePlayerColor.textColor;
        oldPlayer.panel.color = inactivePlayerColor.panelColor;
        oldPlayer.text.color = inactivePlayerColor.textColor;
    }

    void GameOver(string winningPlayer)
    {
        SetBoardInteractable(false);
        if (winningPlayer == "draw")
        {
            SetGameOverText("It's a Draw!");
            SetPlayerColorsInactive();
        }
        else
        {
            SetGameOverText(winningPlayer + " Wins!");
        }
        restartButton.SetActive(true);
    }

    void SetGameOverText(string value)
    {
        gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
        gameOverText.text = value;
    }

    public void RestartGame()
    {
        moveCount = 0;
        gameOverPanel.SetActive(false);
        restartButton.SetActive(false);
        SetPlayerButtons(true);
        SetPlayerColorsInactive();
        startInfo.SetActive(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < gridSpaceList.Length; i++)
        {
            gridSpaceList[i].text = "";
        }
    }

    private void SetBoardInteractable(bool toggle)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridSpaceList.Length; i++)
        {
            gridSpaceList[i].button.interactable = toggle;
        }
    }

    void SetPlayerButtons(bool toggle)
    {
        playerX.button.interactable = toggle;
        playerO.button.interactable = toggle;
    }

    void SetPlayerColorsInactive()
    {
        playerX.panel.color = inactivePlayerColor.panelColor;
        playerX.text.color = inactivePlayerColor.textColor;
        playerO.panel.color = inactivePlayerColor.panelColor;
        playerO.text.color = inactivePlayerColor.textColor;
    }
}
```

And the other script looks like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GridSpace : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Button button;
    public string text;
    public Image image;

    private GameController gameController;

    public void SetGameControllerReference(GameController controller)
    {
        gameController = controller;
    }

    public void SetSpace()
    {
        text = gameController.GetPlayerSide();
        image.sprite = gameController.GetPlayerSideImage();
        button.interactable = false;
        gameController.EndTurn();
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont show what gridspace is

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Appears that the code should work ok. I isolated the access to text, and it does work.**

```
void Awake()
{
    //SetGameControllerReferenceOnButtons();
    EndTurn();
    //gameOverPanel.SetActive(false);
    // moveCount = 0;
    //restartButton.SetActive(false);
}
```

**EndTurn() was isolated to just access the gridSpaceList[0...].text:**

```
public void EndTurn()
{
   // moveCount++;

    if (gridSpaceList[0].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[1].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[2].text == playerSide)
    {
        //GameOver(playerSide);
    }
    else if (gridSpaceList[3].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[4].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[5].text == playerSide)
    {
       // GameOver(playerSide);
    }
    else if (gridSpaceList[6].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[7].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[8].text == playerSide)
    {
       // GameOver(playerSide);
    }
    else if (gridSpaceList[0].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[3].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[6].text == playerSide)
    {
        //GameOver(playerSide);
    }
    else if (gridSpaceList[1].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[4].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[7].text == playerSide)
    {
        //GameOver(playerSide);
    }
    else if (gridSpaceList[2].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[5].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[8].text == playerSide)
    {
        //GameOver(playerSide);
    }
    else if (gridSpaceList[0].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[4].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[8].text == playerSide)
    {
        //GameOver(playerSide);
    }
    else if (gridSpaceList[2].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[4].text == playerSide && gridSpaceList[6].text == playerSide)
    {
        //GameOver(playerSide);
    }
    else if (moveCount >= 9)
    {
        //GameOver("draw");
    }
    else
    {
        //ChangeSides();
    }
}
```

**Hierarchy**

[image]

**Inspector gridSpaceList array: Did you set all the references? and add text to them?**

[image]

**I also added text values to each of the game objects for testing. Since the above works ok, try following the the object before it gets to EndTurn(), and see what happens...**

Comment: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GridSpace : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Button button;
    public string text;
    public Image image;

    private GameController gameController;

    public void SetGameControllerReference(GameController controller)
    {
        gameController = controller;
    }

    public void SetSpace()
    {
        text = gameController.GetPlayerSide();
        image.sprite = gameController.GetPlayerSideImage();
        button.interactable = false;
        gameController.EndTurn();
    }
}

Comment: Updated the post